# how do i remove comma in the list using for loop?

Tags: python-3.x

I have this code:

```
a = []
num = input('Enter numbers *Separate by using commas:')
for i in num:
    a.append(i)
print(a)
```

and I get this:

```
Enter numbers *Separate by using commas:1,2,3
['1', ',', '2', ',', '3']
```

how do I remove the comma?..and I need to use the for loop...thanks

Comment: I wanted to answer your question, but you deleted the post. when you re-open the question let me know.

Comment: i'm still trying to find some example inside this stackoverflow but still cant find how to build it....hahaha....sorry...i'm still new with python

Comment: Just open a new question. This time write what you tried to do

Comment: I will post it again after 90 minutes...thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this (by default prevents "," to enter in your array in the first place and functional for multi-digit numbers as you pointed out)-

```
      a = []
      num = input('Enter numbers *Separate by using commas:')
      num = num.split(",")   #splits the input string with "," delimiter
      for i in num:
            a.append(i)
      print(a)
```

Comment: why is it when I try to input number like 34 it will separate it into 3 and 4....how to make it into 34?

Comment: That was happening because the input function takes whatever input you type as one whole string hence when you iterate a loop it will process one character at a time. See the edited answer for the code that you need.